# The Area bounded by $y=e^x, 2y+2k-2kx-1-e^2=0$ is minimum for $ k=k_1$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, area

The Area bounded by $y=e^x, 2y+2k-2kx-1-e^2=0$ is minimum for $ k=k_1$; then (where [.] denotes greatest integer function)

A. $[2k_1]\gt5$    $\qquad$     B.  $|2k_1-2\pi|\lt1$  $\qquad$  C. $k_1 \in \mathbb I$ $\qquad$  C. $k_1=\frac pq; p, q$ are integers $q\not=0,1, {-1}$

*my attempt*

I had drawn the graphs of the exponential function and the the straightline and found that for $k\lt0$ we have $\infty$ area enclosed so $k$ must be $\gt0$.  and also the line
$$\frac y{\frac{e^2+1}2-k}+ {x\over1-\frac{e^2+1}{2k}}=1$$

passes through a fixed point $P\equiv\left(1,\frac{e^2+1}2\right)$

so as $k$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$ the line rotates about this fixed point. and this point is above the graph of $y=e^x$. I reached upto this i could not make any further conclusion from here. I had a thought to find the points of intersection in terms of $k$ then integrate but to find the points of intersection seems to be impossible.

Comment: Nice question. What did you try in order to solve it?

Comment: Is this multi correct or single correct

Comment: I have edited it, to tell how far I had approached.

Comment: This is a multi correct competitive exam-based question.